# EF5 Object property won't save in a database

Tags: object, model-view-controller, entity

So I'm creating a simple MVC app that uses the Absence class as a model which holds different properties including an object from the Employee class-another model that holds various properties:

```
public class Absence
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public bool isApproved { get; set; }
    public int employee_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee employee { get; set; }
    public Absence()
    {
        employee = new Employee();
    }
}
```

And I created a controller that has an ActionResult function for the create View:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Absence abs = new Absence();
        return View(abs);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Absence abb)
    {
        Employee emp = database.Employees.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == abb.employee_Id);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(emp.Name);
        abb.employee.Name = emp.Name;
        abb.employee.Surname = emp.Surname;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(abb.employee.Name);
        database.Absences.Add(abb);
        database.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("/Absence");
    }
```

The idea is to talk to the database find an Employee object with the same EmployeeId and set the name and surname of the employee object of the abb object to be the same and after testing it with the debugger I can see that it works.

However when I want to display all the added absences including the name and surname of their employee like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(database.Absences.ToList());
    }
```

The name and surname of all the employees don't show.

It seems that all the properties are saved in the database using entity framework except for the Employee object.

Any ideas for how to save it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try saving the Absences first before updating the employee details? I don't exactly know how your database models are configured and this is just an assumption. The absence that is referencing your employee is not yet available when you are supplying the employee details.

```
Employee emp = database.Employees.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == abb.employee_Id);
database.Absences.Add(abb); //Moved adding here
database.SaveChanges(); // Perform the saving
abb.employee.Name = emp.Name;
abb.employee.Surname = emp.Surname;
database.SaveChanges();
```